# Exception while visiting module-info.class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, Payara Server

Tags: java, java-ee-7, eclipse-kepler, payara

When I try to start my `payara` server unknown `illegalArgumentException` on `module-info.class` error occurs,

```
2017-07-17T20:06:58.042+0530|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2017-07-17T20:06:58.057+0530|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2017-07-17T20:06:58.057+0530|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2017-07-17T20:06:58.073+0530|Info: Created virtual server server
2017-07-17T20:06:58.073+0530|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2017-07-17T20:06:58.709+0530|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2017-07-17T20:06:58.709+0530|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2017-07-17T20:06:59.010+0530|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2017-07-17T20:06:59.011+0530|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2017-07-17T20:06:59.013+0530|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2017-07-17T20:06:59.094+0530|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2017-07-17T20:07:00.849+0530|Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14 ( 20161114-2152 unable to get svn info) for context ''
2017-07-17T20:07:02.397+0530|Severe: Exception while visiting module-info.class of size 281
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-07-17T20:07:02.461+0530|Severe: Exception while visiting module-info.class of size 330
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-07-17T20:07:02.461+0530|Severe: Exception while visiting module-info.class of size 449
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-07-17T20:07:02.477+0530|Severe: Exception while visiting module-info.class of size 267
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-07-17T20:07:02.539+0530|Info: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
2017-07-17T20:07:02.555+0530|Info: Loading application __admingui done in 5,492 ms
2017-07-17T20:07:02.850+0530|Info: WELD-000900: 2.4.1 (Final)
2017-07-17T20:07:03.459+0530|Info: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2017-07-17T20:07:03.475+0530|Info: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2017-07-17T20:07:04.820+0530|Info: Cannot find the resource bundle for the name com.sun.logging.enterprise.system.core.naming for class org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.deployer.ConcurrentObjectFactory using org.glassfish.main.concurrent.impl [41]
2017-07-17T20:07:05.185+0530|Info: Loading application [test-service] at [/test-service]
2017-07-17T20:07:05.524+0530|Info: test-service was successfully deployed in 3,672 milliseconds.
```

Environment used,

```
1. Kepler Service Release 2
2. JDK 1.8 with Java compiler level set to 1.7 in Eclipse
3. pom.xml




<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


4. Payara Server 4.1.1.171
```

Unable to load application, what would be the possible cause for this? How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 7 (u80) or Java 8 (u121, u151), this error could not be eliminated with Payara versions:

- 4.1.2.172
- 4.1.1.171.0.1
- 5.0 beta 1

Instead, [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (u151) with [GlassFish 5](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download) eliminated the class incompatibility error.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `Payara` server from `payara-4.1.2.172` to `payara-4.1.1.171.0.1` is the fix, the possible cause would be compiler mismatch between servers, Wherein `payara-4.1.1.171.0.1` works great with `Java 7`. More explanation from the community would be helpful for more clarity on the possible cause of error.